# Tegra based robotics platform

Tags: android, serial-port, arm, robotics, i2c

I am looking into the possibility of developing a Tegra based robotics platform running Android. To do this I need to be able to preform serial, I2C, and possibly PWM communications, does the Tegra platform have allow this? And does Android support access to this kind of hardware level communication?

Answer (score 0):

For communicating with hardware from the Android, I suggest looking at the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). This will allow you to communicate with external devices (e.g. a [Freeduino](http://shop.moderndevice.com/products/freeduino-usb-host-board)) over the phone's USB port. Besides allowing you to get the project working without opening the phone, this is generally the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the Toradex Colibri modules. You can choose between a Tegra 2 or Tegra 3, or other CPUs

They have PWM, I2C, GPIO.

http://www.toradex.com/products/colibri-arm-computer-modules

In case you are a student you even can get the Hardware for free and win 20'000 USD
http://www.challenge.toradex.com/